# Creating a youtube video list, and saving the links for use offline

Tags: android, listview, youtube

I am trying to develop a activity that will search for videos on youtube, given a search string. Once this search returns, I need to show a listview with thumbnails, title, duration and allow adding the video (not downloading) for reference later.

I know how to create a custom listview.

Now, I need youtube api's to return the search results for me to use.

I have tried the following

1. Calling the youtube activity. But this shows a search results which I have no control on (for obvious reasons). Is there a way to startActivityForResult, not display the search results, and just return the a List ?. I tried searching for the documentation, just could not find it.

   ```
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
       intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
       intent.putExtra("query", "Car Pool videos");
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(intent);
       Globals.forward(this) ;
       finish() ;
   ```
2. [YouTube API's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/youtube_mobileresources) does not have search api's.
3. [Youtube data api's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?hl=de-DE), here I was unable to find anyone who have been able to do it successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thumbnail needs to be created while playing the file. So some offline work was needed for this. Had to manually create a thumbnail and display that during the load.